# How do I install an older version of TestNG plugin in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin, testng

I was trying to install Eclipse testNG plugin, but it installed the latest version of testNG. Is it possible to install an older version?

Comment: Use these links to get testng plugins for eclipse: https://github.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-update-site

Answer (score 0):

As @manojadams stated, use the [git-hub documentation](https://github.com/testng-team/testng-eclipse-update-site) to choose the eclipse update site for the version you want. The site doesn't list all versions, but for java 8, I had to roll back to version 7.4 to get TestNG to work.

Paste the ULR they provide into eclipse's Help->Install New Software 'Work With:' edit box.